# Azure mobile app custom authentication and MobileServiceClient

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, custom-authentication, azure-authentication, mobileserviceclient

I was following custom authentication for my azure mobile app (https://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/custom-authentication-with-azure-mobile-apps)

I created **AuthControll** which accepts username and password and creates token. When i call **MobileServiceClient.InvokeApiAsync("Auth", loginInfoDictionary)**, I receive the user name and token succesfully. I created **new MobileServiceUser(username)** with received token an set it to **MobileSeviceClient.CurrentUser**. But When i call **MobileServiceClient.InvokeApi** over method which requiere authorization, it tells me i am unauthorized.

What i am supposed to do with received token then ? Can i use **MobileServiceClient.InvokeApiAsync** and **MobileServiceClient.GetTable** methods with this type of authorization ? If yes what i am missing ?

Comment: Refer to this document https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/docs/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication.md

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem in my solution on server side. I forgot to specify my url site when creating a token. Like this

```
var signingKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY");
var audience = "https://TheSiteIForgotToSpecify.azurewebsites.net/"; // audience must match the url of the site
var issuer = "https://TheSiteIForgotToSpecify.azurewebsites.net/"; // audience must match the url of the site
JwtSecurityToken token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(
    claims, signingKey, audience, issuer, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
```